# AdDuplex Ad Control keeps showing despite collapsing it

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, adduplex

I’m creating a WinRT (Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1) app in which I placed an AdDuplex ad control in one of its pages.

The user of the app can choose to remove the ad (with an IAP). When they do, I set the `Visibility` of the AdDuplex ad control  to `Collapsed`, from the page ViewModel.

This part works fine; however, after some time, **while the user is still on the page**, AdDuplex ad control suddenly becomes visible again and starts showing ads.

At the beginning, I thought this is the behavior of IAP when using `CurrentAppSimulator`, although it didn’t make sense to me, since I have nothing in the code that reacts to license changes and hence setting the control back to `Visible`. Yet, I tested `license.IsActive` for my " NoAd” product and got `true`, indicating that the license is valid.

The following is a simplified part of my code:

**MyPage.xaml**

```
<ad:AdControl
    AdUnitId="{StaticResource AdUnitId}"
    AppKey="{StaticResource AdAppKey}"
    IsTest="True"
    CollapseOnError="True"
    Visibility="{Binding IsNoAdPurchased, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityInvertedConverter}}"/>
```

**MyPageViewModel.cs**

```
private async void RemoveAd()
{
    this.IsNoAdPurchased = await this.storeService.PurchaseProductAsync(Products.NoAd);
}
```

**StoreService.cs**

```
#if DEBUG
using StoreCurrentApp = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator;
#else
using StoreCurrentApp = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp;
#endif

public sealed class StoreService
{
    public async Task<bool> PurchaseProductAsync(string productId)
    {
        try
        {
            var purchase = await StoreCurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productId);
            return purchase.Status == ProductPurchaseStatus.Succeeded || purchase.Status == ProductPurchaseStatus.AlreadyPurchased;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // The purchase did not complete because an error occurred.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with AdDuplex Ad Control and was fixed in version 9.0.0.13.

Note: don't forget to set `IsTest` to `false` to see the "production" behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo followed by yours and you can refer to it.

xaml part:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="myconverter"></local:MyConverter>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Windows81:AdMediatorControl x:Name="AdMediator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Id="AdMediator-Id-FA61D7FD-4F5F-445D-AB97-DB91618DBC70" Margin="557,287,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible,Converter={StaticResource myconverter}}" />
    <Button Name="btn1" Content="Remove ad" Click="RemoveAd" Visibility="Visible" />
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
public class Recording : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isVisible;

        public Recording()
        {
        }

        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return isVisible;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != isVisible)
                {
                    isVisible = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private Recording recording;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Init();
            recording = new Recording();
            recording.IsVisible = false;
            this.DataContext = recording;

        }

        private async void Init()
        {
            StorageFile proxyFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("in-app-purchase.xml");
            await CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(proxyFile);
        }

        public async Task<bool> PurchaseProductAsync(string productId)
        {
            try
            {
                var purchase = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productId);
                return purchase.Status == ProductPurchaseStatus.Succeeded || purchase.Status == ProductPurchaseStatus.AlreadyPurchased;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // The purchase did not complete because an error occurred.
                return false;
            }
        }

        private async void RemoveAd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            recording.IsVisible = await this.PurchaseProductAsync("product2");
        }


    }

    public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value is Boolean && (bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I have tested it and after buying the product,the ad will no longer show.

Also I would like to advise you to use another method without binding.

xaml part:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Windows81:AdMediatorControl x:Name="AdMediator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Id="AdMediator-Id-FA61D7FD-4F5F-445D-AB97-DB91618DBC70" Margin="557,287,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Visibility="Visible" />
        <Button Name="btn1" Content="Remove ad" Click="Button_Click" Visibility="Visible" />
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
namespace AdmediatorTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Init();

            LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
            if (!licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["product2"].IsActive)
            {
                btn1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                btn1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        private async void Init()
        {
            StorageFile proxyFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("in-app-purchase.xml");
            await CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(proxyFile);
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LicenseInformation licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
            if (!licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["product2"].IsActive)
            {
                try
                {
                    await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("product2");
                    if (licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["product2"].IsActive)
                    {
                        AdMediator.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AdMediator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //rootPage.NotifyUser("Unable to buy " + productName + ".", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //rootPage.NotifyUser("You already own " + productName + ".", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Besides I found an [awesome video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-070-Album-Cover-Match-Game-In-App-Purchase-for-Ad-Removal) about removing ad after IAP and you can also refer to it.

Comment: (1) The issue I'm facing is with AdDuplex not AdMediator. I haven't tried the latter, (2) not sure why your advise is to use code-behind instead of ViewModels and how they are different in this situation, (3) "works on my machine" isn't very helpful to me :), and (4) here is a [sample app](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AheKZK3B7g7Fi9xbYjD7_ucTXV2HRg) that reproduces the issue (tried my best to make it as similar to my app as possible).